# Wordpress sidebar sits at bottom of content

Tags: css, wordpress, sidebar

hey I've scrambled through past posts re: this issue but mine doesn't seem to pertain.

here's the blog.css: 
http://pastebin.com/3P71GtRT

here's the url http://phoogoo.com/blogs/phoogoo-u/

i can't figure out how to get the sidebar next to the content at the top of the page, any advice?

Comment: Do you want it inside the light blue content box, with the text pushed sideways? Or do you want it entirely beside the blue content box?

Answer (score 0):

Do do so, and to wrap the articles around the sidebar (instead of creating 2 columns) you would need to move the sidebar inside the archives section.

```
<div class="shrinkwrap">
    <section>
        <section class="archives">
            <aside class="blog-sidebar">
            </aside>
            <article>
            </article>
            <article>
            </article>
            <article>
            </article>
        </section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Then in the CSS you can make the sidebar float to the left and remove the "position: relative".

```
aside {
    float: left;
    /* position: relative; */
}
```

Finally you need to remove the "float: left" from the article tag.

```
article {
    /* float: left; */
}
```

It won't be perfect yet, but that's how you can take care of the positioning. The rest is fine tuning :)